# Python, why Elasticsearch return records not according to the given query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm new in elasticsearch and I'm trying to get data by multi-match query.

Example of data below:

```
{   
    .......
    "_source": {
        "itemid": 40233,
        "value": "176016",
    }
}
{   
    .......
    "_source": {
        "itemid": 40238,
        "value": "176016",
    }
}
{   
    "_index": "uint-2018-12-04",
    .......
    "_source": {
        "itemid": 40203,
        "value": "176016",
    }
}
```

My code:

```
def __init__(self, CustomerName, DeviceID):
    self.client = Elasticsearch(hosts=['***.***.***.***'])
    self.search = Search(using=self.client, index="ind-*").extra(size=50)

def get_data_test(self):
    self.search.query("match", itemid=40233)
    response = self.search.execute()
    for hitX in response.hits.hits:
        print(hitX)
```

It works, but not returning the expected records, 
It returns all records

Answer (score 0):

the `query` method returns a *copy* of the `Search` object. You need to do:

```
s = self.search.query("match", itemid=40233)
response = s.execute()
...
```